# Loading Image content from an array of byte

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I have a REST service that retruns `byte[]`
I like to create an image (`Ext.Img`) which content is the service result

Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve_thumbnail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] retrieveBDocumentThumbnail(@RequestParam String modelName,@RequestParam String modelVersion) throws BdocWebAccessException {
    return service.retrieveBDocumentThumbnail(modelName, modelVersion);
}
```

Image

```
 Ext.create("Ext.Img", {
     src:'tablet/bDocument/retrieve_thumbnail?modelName=MODELE_INT_003_TYPES_DONNEES&modelVersion'
})
```

The service is invocked but I have this message in the javascript Console:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8080/bdoci-tablet/tablet/bDocument/retrieve_thumbnail?modelName=MODELE_INT_003_TYPES_DONNEES&modelVersion".

I think that the problem is related to the format, How can I fix this?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIME type is an HTTP header that indicates what kind of file it is. In this case, it is sending text/plain. It should be indicating this is an image. I don't think your problem is on the client side, but the client is responding to an invalid response on the server side.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve_thumbnail", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
```

Comment: I tried It but, I had the same message:  Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Comment: The problem is your mime type. Can you check the network panel on the javascript console? You should see the request. Under the headers section, you should see the mime type. If it is still text/plain, then that is still your problem.

Comment: Yes the type still: text/plain,

Comment: I have some code that does exactly what you are trying to do. Changing the request mapping with the `produces` flag worked for me. If this is not working you, then you might have something wrong.

Comment: If i put `@RestController` in the Spring controller, I will have this error in the console " Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain" And if I put `@Controller` , I will have the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown return value type [[B]" –"

Comment: The problem is solved,  with some modification in your proposition:
`produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE`